# How do I move a list of files to a list of directories?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have these files from a study and some files (samples) are from the same group, so I created a folder for each group and I want to move the files to the different folders.

I have a table and a list relating each sample (filename) to its corresponding group (directory name). How do I use a bash script to take each sample (first column) and put it into its group directory (second column)?

Comment: please provide the *table* you mentioned in your question

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't have a code because i didnt know where to start. since it was a table with only two columns i thought my description of it would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is the situation:

file: test.txt with files and directory list:

```
file1.txt;dir1
file2.txt;dir2
file3.txt;dir3
```

the directory with files:

```
./dir1
./dir2
./dir3
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./file3.txt
./script.sh
./test.txt
```

bash script code:

```
cat test.txt |
while read line; do
  IFS=';'
  set - $line
  mv $1 $2/
done
```

directory structure after the bash script was used:

bash script.sh

```
./dir1
./dir1/file1.txt
./dir2
./dir2/file2.txt
./dir3
./dir3/file3.txt
./script.sh
./test.txt
```

Comment: You're encouraging low quality posts by answering them.